# How to set the local folder image as BitmapImage source?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, bitmapimage

I am using the `BitmapImage` to set the image source. I tried

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-use-a-bitmapimage

this way to set the local folder image to BitmapImage source, but the image not loaded.

Anyone, please help me how to set the local folder images to an image source (I want this image `"C:\Users\Name\Pictures\CusotmViewImage1.png` and tried

```
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\santhiya.arulsamy\Pictures\CusotmViewImage1.png"
```

like this);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP - Image Uri in Application Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314799/uwp-image-uri-in-application-folder)

Comment: Please also note that UWP and WPF are completely different, folders you can reach in UWP are very limited

Answer (score 1):

UWP is a sandboxed platform, making it unable to directly access the file. What you should do instead is by using `StorageFile` and `StorageFolder` class to access those files by using [**Files/Folders picker**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) and implement it behind the page (`*.xaml.cs`).

Another way to access it is by using a property in the static class [`windows.storage.knownfolders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders) and use the method `GetFileAsync()`,like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14903734/7418444) for example. But keep it mind to add a capability in your app configuration. 
In your case, you can use `windows.storage.knownfolders.pictureslibrary` property, add **picturesLibrary** capability in your app configuration, and get the file by using the method mentioned above.